# Message Box and Sound Play simultaneously - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

In the code below, the song is played first, after which the message is displayed. How to display the **Message Box** and **Sound Play** *simultaneously* in the code below?

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, ByVal hModule As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Boolean

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call PlaySound("c:\windows\media\tada.wav", 0, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)
    Msgbox "Process completed successfully."
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you actually declare `SND_ASYNC` and `SND_FILENAME`?

Comment: Is `Option Explicit` specified? If `SND_ASYNC` and `SND_FILENAME` aren't defined, you're passing `0 Or 0` (i.e. `0`) as the last parameter, which presumably isn't the right value.

Comment: What is your suggestion for code reform? Can you explain more?

Comment: Those constants `SND_ASYNC` and `SND_FILENAME` are not declared. You can't just pass them like this since they will be treated as a variable and will default to 0. So you are essentially just running `Call PlaySound("C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav, 0, 0)` which is not doing what you want it to do. Check out [this link at Chip Pearson's site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/PlaySound.aspx) where he has a good working example of this function with the constants declared in the code.

Comment: Thank you @JNevill! The following line should be added to the code: `Const SND_ASYNC = &H1`

Comment: So don't forget to add the second constant `Const SND_FILENAME = &H20000` as well ... and above all follow @MathieuGuindon 's advice and *force yourself* to use `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, ByVal hModule As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Boolean

Const SND_ASYNC = &H1

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call PlaySound("c:\windows\media\tada.wav", 0, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)
    Msgbox "Process completed successfully."
End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` at the top and your code stops compiling, because `SND_FILENAME` isn't declared anywhere. Either declare `SND_FILENAME` as well, or remove `Or SND_FILENAME` from the function call - it's doing exactly nothing right now.

Comment: The underscore "_" in your API declaration indicates an intentional line break or has to be removed otherwise.